# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp was deleted

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

lastly I'm struggling with Android Crashes from firebase.
We are using unity latest version:

- Firebase App (v7.1.0)
- Firebase Auth (v7.1.0)
- Firebase Crashlytics (v7.1.0)
- Firebase Remote Config (v7.1.0)
- Google Analytics for Firebase (v7.1.0).

We initialize it with the options:

```
Application = firebaseOptions != null ? FirebaseApp.Create(firebaseOptions) : FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
```

Normally the game is working correctly, firebase implementation looks good, events are getting captured etc. Unfortunately, we have a lot of crashes with stacktrace:

Did anyone have the same issue? How to resolve it? We can't reproduce the issue, We even don't know how does it happen at all, as stack trace is running clearly right from the Google team code.

I assume it's a work that is checking if the app wasn't removed from the phone.

````
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp was deleted
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.checkNotDeleted(FirebaseApp.java:439)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getApplicationContext(FirebaseApp.java:126)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.insertOrUpdatePrefs(FirebaseInstallations.java:444)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:401)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$2(FirebaseInstallations.java:377)
       at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$4.run(:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)```
````

Comment: Firebase Installations is a new feature for the 7.1.0 SDK. I don't see any related bugs in the tracker, so you might want to file a report on GitHub ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues ) or a bug report ( https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs ). There is an open issue where you can't override the default app ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/650 ), so perhaps double check for any call into `DefaultInstance` for any Firebase feature. But this doesn't seem related.

Comment: Yes, I have resolved this issue as well, posting an answer

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to resolve an issue.

First of all, it was the problem of overriding  DefaultInstance of the firebase app.
more you can find here:
[Firebase issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/650)

And here is how can you resolve it, links were provided to me by firebase support.
At the moment we are preventing auto initialization of the app, and at runtime, we create a fresh firebase app, it's the first thing we do in the launcher.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

You can also learn more about firebase initialization process here:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html

Comment: How did you solve the problem?